# Trim empty spaces in int array

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I need to trim the trailing spaces at the start and end in this int array and how can I do it, also I am not getting Trim() function anywhere here. Pls suggest me.

```
int[] arrPCT = dtOld.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<int>("PCT")).ToArray();
```

Comment: Please provide some sample input and output data. This should make it clearer as int's cannot be trimmed.

Comment: @John - lets have I type a value 10 and what if I enter empty spaces after 10 and I need to trim them.

Comment: So why you type is a string value and it is this you need to trim before it becomes and array of int's.

Comment: I think Ashutosh Singh has given correct answer. Try that one

Comment: Well this will be done automatically and you don't have to worry about this. Eg: use this code int a = Convert.ToInt16("  10  "); this will work fine, no need to trim.

Comment: Ashutosh is correct using a convert rather than a cast will prevent the need for a explicit trim.

Answer (score 3):

int are numeric values. They don't contain spaces (or any other char). It makes no sense trying to trim them.

Comment: lets have I type a value 10 and what if I enter empty spaces after 10 and I need to trim them.

Comment: @Learner you typed a value 10 as string or int?

Comment: You can not enter int in textbox. Even numbers also string only.

Comment: @Learner we will need more code. What is r? How does the value of the textbox get in r? What does Field<T> implementation look like?

Comment: if you type numeric character in a textbox it treated as string. simply trimming the string will do the job for you. and then you can convert the trimmed string into int.

Comment: @Andrew I'm guessing `dtOld` is a `DataTable` and `r` is a `DataRow` [DataRowExtensions.Field<T> Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

```
int[] arrPCT = dtOld.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<int>("PCT").Trim()).ToArray();
```

If r.Field("PCT") value is of string type.

Comment: I would assume Field<int> tries to convert the value (of r?) and returns an int.

Comment: If the implementation of `Field<int>` is this one: [DataRowExtensions.Field<T> Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891.aspx), then `r.Field<int>("PCT")` would return an `int` thus would never have a `Trim()` function

Comment: that why I didnt used <int>. Otherwise answer is strait forward. If your input is int then there is no way to apply trim() on it.